# Cifs share doesn't preserve permission configuration in smb.conf (775 instead of 777)

Tags: permissions, mount, ubuntu-12.04, samba

So I have a share on ubuntu that is accessed through both ubuntu and windows machines.
my relevant smb.conf is like this:

```
path = /share
create_mask = 0777
force create mode = 0777 
security mask = 0777
directory mask = 2777
force directory mode = 0777
directory security mask = 2777
force directory security mode = 2777
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
valid users = <list of users>
forcegroup = group (all the above users are memebers in this group)
```

the folder "/share" is configured with 777 permissions. Creating new files/directories through windows creates them with 777 permissions alright. mounting the share with cifs like this:

```
//<ip>/share /mnt/sahre cifs credentials=/creds,rw,noperm,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

gives me the permission of 775 for all newly created files/directory. This is causing some serious issues with compatability. if anyone has any suggestion of what should be done or investigated I'd love to hear it!